# How to make a custom hook with useState which can update multiple elements if state changes?

Tags: reactjs

Consider the following example:

```
const useCounter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return [ count, setCount ];
};
const Shower = () => {
  const [ value ] = useCounter();

  console.log(value); //stays 0

  return value;
}

const Setter = () => {
  const [ value, setValue ] = useCounter();

  console.log(value); //updates on click

  return <button onClick={() => setValue(value+1)}>
    Add
  </button>
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Setter />
      <Shower />
    </div>
  );
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'd expect that it will use the same state no matter where and how many times it gets used, and if that state updates, it should update every component which uses it I think.

Any suggestions?

Comment: it seems you want to use the context api here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what react context api try to solve.

```
const CounterContext = React.createContext({
  count: 0,
  setCount: () => null
})

const CounterProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <CounterContext.Provider value={{
      count, setCount
    }}>
      {children}
    </CounterContext.Provider>
  )
}

const useCounter = () => {
  return React.useContext(CounterContext)
};
```

`useCounter` will now provide you the same `count` and `setCount` in every component you call it.

To use it:

```
const Shower = () => {
  const { count } = useCounter();    
  return count;
}

const Setter = () => {
  const { count, setCount } = useCounter();    
  return <button onClick={() => setCount(count+1)}>
    Add
  </button>
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <CounterProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <Setter />
        <Shower />
      </div>
    </CounterProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: So basically it's like calling useState in App, and passing down "state" and "setState" as props to the children right?

Answer (score 1):

`useState` returns a pair of `value` and `setter`. A piece of data and a way to change it, but everytime you instantiate a new Component a new instace of this pair will be created as well. `hooks` are a great way to share statetul `logic` between components, not `state` itself. `Shower` get's called and a instance of `useCounter` is created. `Setter` gets called and a new instance is created. The structure is the same, the `state` is not.

To share `state` between components use `props`, `redux` or `Context API`

Answer (score 0):

When sharing things between functional components, I like to use the pattern below, it is the redux-ish reusable version of Federkun's answer above:

```js
// this component should be an ancestor of component sharing state
// note that it works no matter how deep your subcomponents are in the render tree
class SharedStateContextProvider extends React.Component {
    /* static propTypes = {
        sharedContext: PropTypes.object,
        reducer: PropTypes.func,
        initialState: PropTypes.object,
        children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
            PropTypes.node,
            PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.node),
        ]),
    } */

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            contextValue: { state: props.initialState, dispatch: this.handleDispatch },
        };
    }

    handleDispatch = (action) => {
        const { reducer } = this.props;
        const { contextValue: { state: sharedState } } = this.state;
        const newState = reducer(sharedState, action);
        if (newState !== sharedState) {
            this.setState(
              () => ({
                contextValue: { state: newState, dispatch: this.handleDispatch }
              })
            );
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { sharedContext: Context, children } = this.props;
        const { contextValue } = this.state;
        return (
            <Context.Provider value={contextValue}>
                {children}
            </Context.Provider>
        );
    }
}

// the actual shared context
const CounterContext = React.createContext();

// add as much logic as you want here to change the state
// as you would do with redux
function counterReducer(state, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'setValue':
      return {
        ...state,
        value: action.data
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// counterContext is a prop so the dependency in injected
const Shower = ({ counterContext }) => {
  // well known redux-ish interface
  const { state, dispatch } = React.useContext(counterContext);

  console.log(state.value);

  return state.value;
}

// counterContext is a prop so the dependency in injected
const Setter = ({ counterContext }) => {
  // well known redux-ish interface
  const { state, dispatch } = React.useContext(counterContext);

  console.log(state.value); //updates on click

  return <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'setValue', data: state.value+1 })}>
    Add
  </button>
}

// the actual shared state
const initialCounterState = { value: 0 };

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SharedStateContextProvider
          sharedContext={CounterContext}
          reducer={counterReducer}
          initialState={initialCounterState}
      >
        <Setter counterContext={CounterContext} />
        <Shower counterContext={CounterContext} />
      </SharedStateContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

const root = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```